# Find multiple values in a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

`a` and `b` are two Numpy arrays of integers. They are sorted and without repetitions. `b` is a subset of `a`. I need to find the index in `a` of every element of `b`. Is there an efficient Numpy function that could help, so I can avoid the python loop?

(Actually, the arrays are of `pandas.DatetimeIndex` and Numpy `datetime64`, but I guess it doesn't change the answer.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`numpy.searchsorted()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) can be used to do this:

```
In [15]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20, 25])

In [16]: b = np.array([1, 5, 20, 25])

In [17]: a.searchsorted(b)
Out[17]: array([0, 3, 5, 6])
```

From what I understand, it doesn't require `b` to be sorted, and uses binary search on `a`. This means that it's O(n logn) rather than O(n).

If that's not good enough, there's always [Cython](http://www.cython.org/). :-)

Comment: I wouldn't even think that they'd need a binary search here ... Under the assumption that both are sorted you can easily convince yourself that this can be done in O(N) time.  (Consider the merge stage of a merge-sort).  I'd be interesting to see if a python implementation could beat this under those assumptions.

Comment: @mgilson: You are quite right that the OP's problem can be solved in O(n). What I am saying is that `searchsorted()` solves a more general problem, and therefore can't be O(n).

Comment: Yeah, I was just realizing that.  Too bad they don't have a searchdoublesorted function :)